# Cannot edit widgets in WYSIWYG editor anymore

Tags: magento-1, patches, widgets, wysiwyg, tinymce

Recently, editing widgets in the WYSIWYG editor does not work anymore.

The browser console shows the following error when I click on a widget:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1.
    at Editor.<anonymous> (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:15327)
    at Dispatcher.dispatch (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:6000)
    at DOMUtils.c (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:184650)
    at j (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:58627)
    at HTMLDocument.y (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:58785)
(anonymous) @ tiny_mce.js:1
dispatch @ tiny_mce.js:1
c @ tiny_mce.js:1
j @ tiny_mce.js:1
y @ tiny_mce.js:1
tiny_mce.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1.
    at Editor.<anonymous> (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:15327)
    at Dispatcher.dispatch (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:6000)
    at DOMUtils.c (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:184650)
    at j (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:58627)
    at HTMLDocument.y (http://example.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1:58785)
```

And the popup to create a new widget appears, instead of the one to edit the existing widget.

I found the behavior on different versions of Magento CE 1.x and EE 1.x, in Chrome, regardless of the OS. Can it be related to the recent security patch SUPEE-9767?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it is not related to the patch, but to the latest Chrome update (**Chrome 58**) which got rolled out around the same time. TinyMCE uses deprecated features that were removed in that version.

Magento 2.0 and 2.1 are affected as well (see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9518)

It seems to be a problem with images in general, here's a related issue in the TinyMCE project: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3611 **TinyMCE 4.6 fixes the issue.**

Now you have the following options:

- replace the bundled TinyMCE version with 4.6 or newer
- wait until Magento releases a patch that updates TinyMCE and until then use other browsers (currently only Chrome seems to be an issue) and hope that they don't remove the deprecated features that soon.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research, I've been lazy about it ^^

Answer (score 4):

A quick fix I applied was overriding the tiny_mce JS file with my own patched version.

```
        editor.onClick.add(function(editor, e) {
            e = e.target;

-           // Workaround for bug, http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12250
-           // WebKit can't even do simple things like selecting an image
-           // Needs tobe the setBaseAndExtend or it will fail to select floated images
            if (/^(IMG|HR)$/.test(e.nodeName)) {
-               selection.getSel().setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, 1);
+               /** Removed webkit bug fix - it breaks in Chrome 58 */
+                selection.select(e);
            }

            if (e.nodeName == 'A' && dom.hasClass(e, 'mceItemAnchor') {
```

For a lazy hack. Highlight the image with your cursor (as if you are selecting text). Once highlighted, it is clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, [TylerSN](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187227/60357)

In my case, the code that had to be removed looked like this:

```
if (tinymce.isWebKit && e.nodeName == 'IMG')
    t.selection.getSel().setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, 1);
```

**Please note:** It was an original tiny_mce release (v3.5.4, 2011-09-06), *not a Magento favour*. However, I came across this question while searching for `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1. at Editor.<anonymous>` and wanted to add the solution for other people's reference. Hope the slightly "off-topic" can be excused in this circumstance.